# How To Append (Or Other Method) a Lot of HTML Code?

Tags: jquery, html, append, target

I need to append a lot of HTML code. To improve readability, I don't want to write that all in one line, but split them as regular HTML. That would be like 15 new-lines or something. The problem is that JavaScript doesn't allow me to do that.

```
var target = $('.post .comment_this[rel="' + comment_id + '"]').parent().parent();

target.append('
    <div class="replies">
        <p>...</p>
        <img src="" alt="" />
    </div>
');
```

Basically, I need to add HTML in that place.

I need to add some variables too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
    target.append(' <div class="replies">'+
            '<p>...</p>'+
            '<img src="" alt="" />'+
        '</div>'
    );
```

or

```
    target.append(' <div class="replies">\
            <p>...</p>\
            <img src="" alt="" />\
        </div>'
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

[Creating multiline strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/multiline-strings-in-javascript)

Comment: I wrap each new line into `'quotes'` and added `+` before them. It works and looks a little bit better then when it was all in one line.

Answer (score 1):

```
target.append(' ?>
    <div class="replies">
        <p>...</p>
        <img src="" alt="" />
    </div>
<?');
```

Separate the html and php with the close/open php tags and it should work fine..
when adding var's in the html, just use the tags again, like this: `<? $hello ?>`

Comment: OP makes no mention of PHP.

Comment: Nope OP didn't, and apparently I'm to retarded to read what OP actually wanted and used. NO idea why i assumed OP used php? I take the bullet on that :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert variables to html, you can use some templating library like [jQuery.template](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/)

Answer (score 0):

As of 2015, ECMA 6, you can do this:

```
target.append(`
    <div class="replies">
        <p>...</p>
        <img src="" alt="" />
    </div>
`);
```

Answer (score -1):

use html() instead of append

```
target.html('<div class="replies"><p>...</p><img src="" alt="" />,</div>');
```