# How to append huge amounts of html code via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am struggling to append huge amounts of html code. I found this answer [How To Append (Or Other Method) a Lot of HTML Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545944/how-to-append-or-other-method-a-lot-of-html-code) which I followed but I am getting an illegal argument error. Can anyone suggest a better way to manage this?

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/2ne/pen/EkIep)

JS

```
$(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
    $("body").append(codeBlock);
  });
});

var codeBlock = $("<div class='code-block'>\
    <div class='select-event'>\
        <label>Start</label>\
        <select>\
            <option>when the Run button is pressed</option>\
            <option>when the object is pressed</option>\
            <option data-option='keyoption'>when a keyboard key is pressed</option>\
        </select>\
        <span class='key-press-wrapper'>\
            <label>Key</label>\
            <input id='keyPress' placeholder='Press Key'>\
        </span>\
    </div>\
    <div class='insert-block'>\
        <label>Insert code blocks here</label>\
        <ul id='sortable' class='connectedSortable'></ul>\
    </div>\
</div>\");
```

Comment: You don't need quotes around 'codeBlock'. `$('body').append(codeblock)`

Comment: Amended, thanks for the quick spot

Comment: That's not a huge amount of html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am getting an illegal argument error.
>
> ```
> </div>\");
> ```

That's an odd error, probably it should be "not a valid string literal" or some kind of that. You're escaping the ending string delimiter, which you shouldn't. Remove the backslash in the last line.

Answer (score 2):

Remove last slash at `</div>\")`

Answer (score 2):

Using a template engine is definitely the best solution.

e.g. https://github.com/janl/mustache.js

Comment: This could be a useful plugin to use on future projects. Good find